# Restoring table from duplicated in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups

In SQL Server, I'm creating a backup table using the query below, this gives me an copy of the table `Original` named `Backup`:

```
select * 
into Backup 
from Original
```

How can I use my `Backup` table to restore all data to the `Original` (including id's)?

The original table contains ~20 columns and have 1 or more foreign keys pointing at its id.

Some entries from the `Original` may have been deleted, no new entries have been added.

I where thinking about doing something like:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Original

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Original ON;

INSERT INTO Original (id, val1, val2,....)
    SELECT id, val1, val2,....
    FROM Backup;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Original OFF;
```

but I can't truncate a table being referenced by a foreign key, and without emptying the table, the `INSERT` can run in to duplicated id's

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). If the column is a Primary Key, referenced by Foreign keys, then why do you *want* to delete all those rows? Doing so will create orphaned rows in the other tables, or will delete them **all** due to cascading. What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: Why not use a real backup?

Comment: Script the keys as drop and create, and run the drop before truncating, then reapply the keys. As @lamu said though, there is potential pitfalls deleting keyed values anyhow, so be aware of what you want your data to look like before running!

Comment: @Larnu From a program I need to delete a subset of them (around 100k) then preform some other operation, these can fail. If these operations fail i need to restore the deleted rows. I don't necessary want to delete all of them, I just need to put the rows that where deleted back in to the Original table, from the Backup table.

Comment: What you are after, then, is called a `TRANSACTION`. What *you* are trying to do is exactly what I suspected, an XY Problem.

Comment: @Larnu the problem is that the connection to the db is not kept alive between the point where the backup is created and it possibly needs to be restored. The operations in between take a significant amount of time (involves some hvy rendering). it is my understanding that a transaction is only possible if the db connection is maintained? am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem). What you think you want to do, and what you really need to do are completely different. YOu have described Y to us, but actually you want to do X.

This answer is based on your comment below:

> From a program I need to delete a subset of them (around 100k) then preform some other operation, these can fail. If these operations fail i need to restore the deleted rows. I don't necessary want to delete all of them, I just need to put the rows that where deleted back in to the Original table, from the Backup table.

This is a trivial thing to do in SQL Server, you just need to use transactions. In very simple psuedo-SQL terms:

```sql
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION DoWork;

    --Do your logic here

    --Do you need to also ROLLBACK under some scenario?
    IF {Some Boolean Logic}
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DoWork;
    ELSE
        COMMIT TRANSACTION DoWork;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DoWork;
    THROW;

END CATCH;
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! aren't transactions requiring the db connection to be kept alive?

Comment: Yes, you would do this in a single connection, @user10483669 .